# Why does my Windows keyboard type other language letters and how can I stop it?

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-11

Keyboard typing another letters

Hi, I'm having issue with my windows keyboard settings  and I'm using window 11 for your reference. whenever I try to type fast using my keyboard then it types some letters of other english like language which have curves or lines into the letters. It generally occurs when I press space just after the key press. can you please tell me how to stop this this is so irritating and sometimes there's one pop-up shows up at the top of the window which gives options to select which letter you want to choose. the letters that I'm taking about looks like this "é".

please reply soon.
thanks,

Sahil Dhingra.